# How is a birthday attack actually performed?

Tags: hash, brute-force

I thought I understood the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) until I tried to actually implement it. Either I'm implementing it wrong, or there's something wrong with my interpretation of the resulting probabilities. Because when I simulate it, it takes greater than 2^(N/2) tries.

I simplified it to the problem of choosing random numbers until I choose one I've already chosen before. Already there may be problems, as the time complexity may not be equivalent to a realistic birthday attack. But if it's wrong, I expect it's on the conservative side, since this should be the easiest way to find a collision.

Here is my full code (Python 3). It tries to find a collision between two random 8-bit numbers. It repeats this 100,000 times, and reports the average and median number of tries.

```
import random
def birthday_attack(choices):
  tries = 0
  max_tries = choices**2
  chosen = set()
  choice = None
  while choice not in chosen and tries < max_tries:
    tries += 1
    if choice is not None:
      chosen.add(choice)
    choice = random.randrange(choices)
  return tries
trials = 100000
tries = [birthday_attack(2**8) for i in range(trials)]
print(sum(tries)/trials)
tries.sort()
print(tries[trials//2])
```

The result is consistently an average of about 20.7 tries. But it should take 16, as 2^(8/2) = 2^4 = 16!

What am I missing here, and how would a proper 2^(N/2) birthday attack be performed?

Comment: Considering the birthday problem equivalent of your question (probability of at least two out of $n$ 8-bit numbers being the same), [20 is right about where the probability reaches 0.5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+(2%5E8)!%2F((2%5E8)%5En+*+(2%5E8+-+n)!)).

Comment: @muru Right, so the birthday attack seems to be slightly different from the classic birthday paradox scenario. My question is how? What are the steps performed where you find a collision in an avg of 16 tries instead of 20?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the birthday attack, but it seems to be for generating a collision for a hash function. IIUC, your hash function here is the identity function?

Comment: @muru Yeah, that's a good way to put it. The hash function here is f(x) = x. Or f(x) = x % 2^8, to be more precise.

Comment: So, the article says a collision is expected by about sqrt(πH/2), and H here is 2^8, so ~ 20... Which still agrees with what you see. Are you expecting the attack to take literally 2^(N/2) tries instead of taking O(2^(N/2)) tries?

Comment: @muru Ohh, is that it? When people talk about 2^(N/2) attempts they actually mean O(2^(N/2))?

Comment: @muru Yeah, so sqrt(20π/2) ≈ 20.053, which is close to what I'm getting (20.7). However, it's not the same and not even within the range of variation I'm seeing. Maybe this should be my new question: exactly how many tries should it take?

Comment: as for O(...), yes. As for 20.7 v 20.05, you do realise those formulae are approximate? For example, the article says 300 tries for a 16-bit hash, but the formula gives ~320, because it's an approximation. The difference between 20.7 and 20.05 is negligible. I think you're getting a bit too hung up on "exact" numbers.

Comment: @muru Okay, yeah, I'm not sure it was clear that the formula gives an approximation of the mean, not the exact mean. Is there any simple formula for the exact mean, or is it a complicated computation?